# C# - Getting the current day of the month without month/year

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to get the day of the month as an int/string? E.G it's the 5th of June, I want the system to return 5 to me.

Comment: Which time zone are you interested in? Basically, `DateTime.UtcNow.Day` or `DateTime.Now.Day`... either way, it's the `Day` property you want. If that isn't what you want, please clarify the question. (Did you look through the `DateTime` documentation before asking your question?)

Comment: That's in the .NET Doc. you don't need to ask this.

Comment: DateTime.Now.Day worked, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easily you can get the day of month by returning

```
DateTime.Today.Day
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use the `DateTime.Day` property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var day = dt.Day;
```

Answer (score 1):

sure,

as an integer, it's just `DateTime.Today.Day`
    as a string it's `DateTime.Today.Day.ToString("0")`